# JQuery TAB on click with other attr('href')

Tags: jquery, tabs, click

I have this code in my jquery script:

```
 $('.content-box ul.content-box-tabs li a ').click( // When a tab is clicked...

 function () { 
 $(this).parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass('current'); // Remove "current" class from all tabs      
 $(this).addClass('current'); // Add class "current" to clicked tab
 var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); // Set variable "currentTab" to the value of href of clicked tab
 $(currentTab).siblings().hide(); // Hide all content divs
 $(currentTab).show(); // Show the content div with the id equal to the id of clicked tab
 return this;
  }
 );
```

and this code in may view php:

```
<div class="content-box-header">

<h3>Content box</h3>

   <ul class="content-box-tabs">
     <li><a href="#tab1" id="tab1">Table</a></li> <!-- href must be unique and match the id of target div -->
     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('examples/country_management')?>" id="tab2">Countries</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('examples/channel_management')?>" id="tab3">Channels</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('examples/programs_management/')?>" id="tab4" class="default-tab">Programs</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear"></div>
```

Now. I need to use other atripute in .attr('href') or .prop('href'), not href, but id, title...
If i use that code my tabs work but is not stay in active position, it's active only in load process.
If i use other atribute that href my link directory of tabs is right by tabs not work.

Can you help me.
Sorry for my english.
THX.